# Transaction haven`t got

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core-accounts

5 days ago some Pokerroom sent to my Bitcoin Core wallet a slight amount of bitcoin. I checked it on Blockchain, it's OK. But, unfortunately, still there is no bitcoins in my wallet. I've also sent email here - contact@bitcoincore.org with explanation of the problem.

Who's already gone through situation like this please give me advice on what to do.

Many thanks,
Kirill

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information, such as: what is the receiving address you gave the Poker site? Do you have a tx id for the withdrawal? Is your bitcoin-core wallet fully synced to the network?

Comment: Address         16QQtvsmKExMFojtq5hM6Xpks9Uc5XkmxF
Hash 160  3b46249208fc3d73da62001f238499b52c96d138

Comment: Until now my wallet isn`t fully synced with the network.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bitcoin-core wallet will need to finish syncing with the network before it will display your balance.

Comment: How could I synce it more faster? Number of the not synced blocks - 91 451 (progress 57,%). I don`t have enough free space on my computer as well - 10 GB / 227 GB.

Comment: If you don't have enough free space for the full blockchain, you can instead run a 'pruned node', so that old and un-needed transactions are deleted from your hard drive after they are validated. Look up 'pruning' for more info. There isn't really any way to speed it up, except for using a faster computer, a high-speed internet connection, or an SSD instead of an HDD.

Comment: You could also try using a light-wallet that doesn't sync the entire chain instead, but now that you have sent funds to your bitcoin-core wallet, you would need to dump the private keys from it, and import them into the light-wallet, which is a little bit more of an advanced operation, but it is possible.